# HD Partitioning after a corrupted GPT table

Tags: partitioning

My HD had 3 partitions, one of 20 GB for the OS, the second with 100 GB and the remaining space was used by the third.

The thing is, the tables have been corrupted and now I can't access any of those partitions. Worse yet, 2nd and 3rd partitions were encrypted with LUKS...

Is there any way to use gparted or other command to recreate the partitions (assuming I know their position and size) in a way it doesn't write any information that would overwrite data where there once was an encrypted volume? Re-creating the initial table is all I need...

Anyhow, I do have a backup for the important stuff, but my home folder was one I supposed I wasn't going to need to recover...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sure; use the "create partition" command in `gdisk` or recent versions of `fdisk`.

Comment: The relevant command being `n` in both cases. Note that you need the *exact* (to the sector) start points for this to work. For future reference, `gdisk` includes a partition table backup option (`b` on the main menu) so you can save your partition table data to a file.